# django AJAX POST request is showing 500 error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

MY ajax code is

```
   $(function(){    
        $('#search').keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:"/abc/search/",
       data:{'search_text':$('#search').val(),
              'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
       },
       success: searchsuccess,
       datatype: 'html'
     });
   });
 });

 function searchsuccess (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
 $('#search_result').html(data);
}
```

my view is

```
def search_college(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    search_text=request.POST['search_text']
else:
    search_text = ""
colleges = Collage.objects.filter(col_name__contains=search_text)
render(request, "ajax_search.html", {'colleges': colleges})
```

my Form is-

```
             <form>{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search">
            </form>
```

I am 500 (internal server error ) after ajax post call? How can i solve it??

Comment: this is not error or ajax it is server error

Comment: Remove the `datatype` from your JS code and see if it works.

Comment: problem is with your `url`

Comment: i had problem with view. I forget to write return before render in search_college function. Its working now.

Comment: thank you for help